# Access data from onmessage function from a websocket in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have established a websocket connect from my server to my client machine. I have parsed the data into an object and would like to access the data for representation on my front end.

```js
import './App.css';
import { w3cwebsocket as W3CWebSocket } from "websocket";
import { Component } from 'react';

const client = new W3CWebSocket('ws://xyz:9080/user');

class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        client.open = () => {
            console.log("Connected");
        };

        client.onmessage = (e) => {
            const object = JSON.parse(e.data);
            console.log(object.Snapshot);

        }
        client.onclose = () => {
            console.log("Closed...");
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (<div className="App">
                    <h2>{ object }</h2>
                </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

I want to access my object variable from the on message function and use it as a variable in my render function. How do I approach this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add [local state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class) to your class. State is a fairly foundational part of `react` and how it is able to reactively rerender components, so it sounds like you need to spend some time reading the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) to familiarize yourself with the basics.

That said, I'll provide an updated version of your code for demonstration purposes. Note that you used `client.open` when you meant `client.onopen`, so I've made that correction below:

```
import "./App.css";
import { w3cwebsocket as W3CWebSocket } from "websocket";
import { Component } from "react";

const client = new W3CWebSocket("ws://xyz:9080/user");

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { object: "" };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    client.onopen = () => {
      console.log("Connected");
    };

    client.onmessage = (e) => {
      const object = JSON.parse(e.data);
      this.setState({ object: object });
      console.log(object.Snapshot);
    };

    client.onclose = () => {
      console.log("Closed...");
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h2>{this.state.object}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Also, since it seems that you're probably just starting out with `react`, I would strongly recommend that instead of the old-style class-based components, you use learn to use [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) and functional components, which is just an overall much cleaner and easier to reason about way to write `react` code. We could rewrite your code as follows using the `useState` and `useEffect` hooks in an `App` function:

```
import "./App.css";
import { w3cwebsocket as W3CWebSocket } from "websocket";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [object, setObject] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const client = new W3CWebSocket("ws://xyz:9080/user");

    client.onopen = () => {
      console.log("Connected");
    };

    client.onmessage = (e) => {
      const newObj = JSON.parse(e.data);
      setObject(newObj);
      console.log(newObj.Snapshot);
    };

    client.onclose = () => {
      console.log("Closed...");
    };

    return () => client.OPEN && client.close();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>{object}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Note per the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) that `useEffect` with an empty dependency array is more or less equivalent to `componentDidMount`. Note also that even though `client` is defined in a local scope, it won't be garbage-collected, because it is referenced in the cleanup closure (the return value of the arrow function passed to `useEffect`).

Finally, note that I haven't used the `websocket` package before, so I don't know if your usage is correct or optimal. This answer is about how to manage state in `react`, not how to use `websocket` in a `react` application.

Comment: This still doesn't work. I get an error saying "Objects are not valid as a React child", Is there a way to render objects before I can use them on the DOM.

Comment: I answered without any information as to the shape of `object`. If it is anything other than a simple string, you will need to parse it somehow. The normal rules of writing html apply: a valid child of an `<h2>` tag is of course a string of some sort, not a complex javascript object. If, for example, `object.Snapshot` is a string, you could use that in the render function/function's component's return.